# Is it possible to respec (reset) the passive skill points?

Tags: path-of-exile

So far, I've been spreading my passive skill points here and there in [the *huge* passive tree](http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree).  I'll  probably want to change it to a more clever distribution later, when I'll have a better understanding of the game.  Is it possible, and how ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are ways to make small changes to your skill point distributions in the passive skill tree, however the intention is not that you simply 'reset' the skill tree and instead make a new character if you want to make a large quantity of changes. This is [detailed on the Path of Exile website](http://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree):

> If you want to adjust your passive build during gameplay, there are Passive Skill Refund points available from quests or relatively rare items in the game that can be found or traded for. Fixing mistakes with a character build or improving small-medium sized aspects is relatively easy, but our intention is that players who want to try substantially divergent character builds are encouraged to play a new character through the game, organically leveling it up rather than just respeccing into it.

You'll get a few respec points from quests which each allow you to remove a single skill point, so you can try out big nodes and undo little mistakes. This doesn't remove the need to plan your skill point distribution ahead and you'll still have to pay attention.

You can refund individual skill points by using [Orbs of Regret](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Orb_of_Regret) ([purchased from Yeena in Act 2](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Vendor_recipes#Direct_Purchases_from_Vendor)) but if you're level 20 or above it's easier to just make a new character.

[image: Orb of Regret]

It is not possible to completely reset your passive skill tree.

Comment: When using a respec point, are you restricted to only removing passives that are at the end of your progress down a specific path (i.e. no skills that are prerequisites for another skill you've taken)?

Comment: yes you are - which is why once you're past level ~20 it's easier to just reroll your character. They're called prerequisites for a reason!

Comment: I figured that was probably the case, but it's good to have confirmation.  Thanks!

Comment: From time to time, you are given full passive skill resets when GGG launches a major update. This was the case for Awakening and Ascendancy. Depends on how often you play, though.